# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to install cheese

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic$ sudo apt-get install cheese
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

how to solve this issue please help.

Comment: Reboot and try again.

Comment: Have a look at this answer:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem/102084#15436

Answer (score 51):

#### Warning: This should not be the first thing you try. Read the answers on the [linked duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/15433/301745) before proceeding.

---

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: In my specific case I removed the lock here -> `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` - after lock removed it was able to install -> `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Comment: I still get an error: `unable to lock the administration directory /var/lib/dpkg`