# Can't uninstall PHPmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, phpmyadmin, lock, syntax

My PHPmyadmin (PMA) install was stuck. I started a new session and when doing apt-get purge phpmyadmin I got:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable).
>
> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is
>   another process using it?

I ran these in Google and found two issues here; Highest answers suggest removing lock file (as well as it's cached version), but that didn't help:

- [E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346143/e-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-open-11-resource-temporarily-unavai)
- [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer should be tried as well for Ubuntu 16.04, I would advise to try it second:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
sudo rm -r phpmyadmin.*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo phpdismod mcrypt mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo sed -i 's/Include \/etc\/phpmyadmin\/apache.conf/ /g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Attention: you might have to use sudo in other commands informed above, otherwise you might get "permission denied" message.

Comment: @MarceloÁgil fixed.